# htaccess RewriteRule for /category/page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess defined such rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ___show-content.php?$1
```

Created file `___show-content.php` which includes code

```
echo (ltrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'/')). '<br/>';
```

If i type `www.mydomain.com/some-page` then `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'` is `/some-page`. This works as expected.

But if I type `www.mydomain.com/some-page/another-page`, then get see `Not Found The requested URL /some-page/another-page was not found on this server.` I see nothing with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'`. If one trailing slash (after domain name), then works ok, but if more than one, does not works.

What need to modify for RewriteRule to work with more than one trailing slash in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your regex to capture URI is only allowing one and more of `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` characters in it.

Make your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)$ ___show-content.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```